# Trouble connecting to SQL Server Express with Node.js

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, sockets

I am currently trying to establish a connection to a SQL Server instance on my local machine with the following Node program, `app.js`:

```
var sql = require('mssql');

sql.connect("mssql://sa:temp2@localhost/Northwind").then(function() {
    // Query 

    new sql.Request().query('select * from TableName').then(function(recordset) {
        console.dir(recordset);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And the error:

> { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433
>
> at Connection.
>   (C:\Users\name\nodeprac\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:378:25)
>
> at Connection.g (events.js:286:16)
>
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>
> at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
>
> at Connection.socketError
>   (C:\Users\name\nodeprac\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:531:14)
>
> at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>
> at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>
> at emitErrorNT (net.js:1272:8)
>
> at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>
> name: 'ConnectionError',
>
> message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED
>   127.0.0.1:1433',
>
> code: 'ESOCKET' }

I've tried a million other ways of establishing a connection with other errors, but I feel like there must be something simple here that I am missing. Also, there is more than one instance of SQLServer Express on my machine. Would removing one help? I've enabled all `TCP/IP` ports for the current server, and set all ports to `1433`

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to connect via SSMS first off?

Comment: Also -- try Machinename instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 -- tends to be more reliable.

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to SSMS; I've tried my machine name but to no avail. Question: is it possible that because there are two SQL Server instances that it is fudging up the connection? In SSMS, when checking server properties I have one server named `MachineName\FirstInstance` and another `MachineName\SecondInstance`.

Comment: Yeah, you need to specify the instance name in your connection strings... I don't know node.js well enough to answer that part, but it definitely required.

Comment: Yeah, same. I have it working in my ASP.NET project, but was hoping to develop a facsimile of sorts using Node.js and Express.js instead of the C# API I currently have. I'll keep trying though. Thanks!

Comment: Quick Google --- http://csdoc.org/ shows a different approach to setting connection options for mssql.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that one too unsuccessfully with the same error message. I think that I'll try to remove one of the server instances and see what happens. I don't know why that would work, but it is the only thing I haven't tried yet; and, it is a trivial instance anyway, so nothing lost in removing it.

Comment: That won't strip the instance name from the remaining install.  You have to remove both and reinstall one without the instance name to remove it.  Surely someone here will answer you, I'd suggest waiting a bit first.  There is a solution.

Comment: Hm, now that you mention it, in one of my attempts the error said something along the lines of '...port for SecondInstance could not be found for server MachineName\SQLEXPRESS...'. Now, I'm not sure if that is because my the first server instance I have in this context is named 'SQLEXPRESS' or some other cause. I'll try to reproduce the error and append it to my post for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to restart my system (Like the scrub I am). Works now. The changes in enabling TCP/IP don't take effect unless system is restarted(which SQL Server Configuration Manager tried to tell me).

Comment: you could also re-start the SQL service from ```services.msc``` hit Winkey + r and type ```services.msc``` , you will find a service called ```SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER)``` and this will help you do it without restarting the whole system